# Proof verification: If $a$ and $b$ are integers, with $b > 0$, then $a = qb + r$ for some $q$ and $r$, where $2b \le r < 3b.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are integers, with  $b > 0$, then there exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ satisfying $a = qb + r$, where $2b \le r < 3b$.

In this post, I am only concerned with the part of proving existence and not uniqueness of $q$ and $r$. Here is my proof of existence of $r$:

Let $S = \{a - xb \mid x \in \mathbb Z~ , ~2b \le a - bx < 3b \}$. If possible, let $S$ be empty. So,
$$\forall x \in \mathbb Z ~,~ (a - xb < 2b ~\vee ~ a - xb \ge 3b)$$
i.e.
$$\forall x \in \mathbb Z ~,~ \left(x > \frac a b - 2 ~\vee~ x \le \frac a b - 3 \right) \tag{1}$$

However, in the interval $\left(\dfrac a b - 3~ , ~ \dfrac a b - 2\right]$ there exists an integer such that $(1)$ becomes false. Since we have reached a contradiction, therefore our assumption of $S$ being empty is false and so it is non- empty which proves the existence of $q$ and $r$.

Is my proof legit?

Comment: if you already know the Division Algorithm then simply apply that to write $\,a-2b = qb + r\,$ for $\,0\le r < b$ then add $2b$ to both sides. More generally we can choose any consecutive sequence of $b$ integers as a complete set of reps for remainders $\bmod b\,$ (provable via the same sort of shift conjugation to standard reps).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Yes I do know the division algorithm. Its just that I have seen a similar proof of division algorithm and wanted to make a proof along the same lines.

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explaining the reason for downvoting? Maybe I can improve the post.

Comment: You would also need to *prove* that every interval $(r,r+1]$ contains an integer. Usually in number theory the division algorithm is proved before a (*rigorous*) development of fractions, and the proof is from first principles using induction, e.g. by showing that $\,a-b\Bbb Z\,\cap\, \Bbb N\,$ is nonempty so has a least element $\,r\,$ (necessarily $\,r<b\,$ else $r-b$ would be a smaller  such natural). The same method works in your case - as I said above. I have no idea why your question was downvoted.