# Show that if $a, b \in Z $ and $a \gt 0$ then there exists a unique pair of $q, r \in Z$ that satisfies $b = aq + r$ and $2a \le r \lt 3a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm learning Number Theory on my own for competitive maths. The textbook I'm using is the part of the Olympiad syllabus in my country, so the problems are picked and adapted from other textbooks. I'm not quite sure where this particular one came from.

The book presents the proof for the division algorithm and I am asked to prove this case.

Show that if $a, b \in Z $ and $a \gt 0$ then there exists a unique pair of $q, r \in Z$ that satisfies $b = aq + r$ and $2a \le r \lt 3a$

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. If $a = 1$, there's no integer $r$ where $2 \lt r \lt 3$. Also, if $a \mid b$, then $a \mid r$, so there's no $2a \lt r \lt 3a$. I suspect it should be $2a \le r \lt 3a$ instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you John Omielan, I have spotted typos in this textbook before. Could you please provide the proof for the case that you mentioned?

Comment: You're welcome. For me, or anyone else here, to best help you, please first edit into the question more context, in particular what you've tried using my suggested correction, and anything you had difficulty with.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Ok I'll get to that.

Comment: As I wrote in [this dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2435005/242), if you already know the Division Algorithm then simply apply that to write $\,a−2b=qb+r$ with $\,0\le r<b,\,$ then add $\,2b\,$ to both sides. More generally we can choose any consecutive sequence of $b$ integers as a complete set of reps for remainders $\!\bmod b\,$ (provable via the same sort of shift conjugation to standard reps)

Comment: Special case of the result on arithmetic progressions being a complete residue system in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866966/242) in the linked dupe. Ask questions here if that is not clear.

Comment: There is a typo: one of your inequalities on $\,r\,$ should not be strict (probsbly $\,2a\le r <     3a\,$ is intended). Also note $\,b,a\,$ are reversed in the dupe (and the the above excerpted comment).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you, I'll look into the post.